# How to query a table with over 200 million rows?

Tags: mysql, limit, database-performance

I have a table USERS with only one column `USER_ID`. These IDs are more than 200M, they are not consecutive and are not ordered. It has an index USER_ID_INDEX on that column. I have the DB in MySQL and also in Google Big Query, but I haven't been able to get what I need in any of them.

I need to know how to query these 2 things:

1) Which is the row number for a particular `USER_ID` (once the table is ordered by `USER_ID`)

For this, I've tried in MySQL:

```
SET @row := 0;
SELECT @row := @row + 1 AS row FROM USERS WHERE USER_ID = 100001366260516;
```

It goes fast but it returns row=1 because the row counting is from the data-set.

```
SELECT USER_ID, @row:=@row+1 as row FROM (SELECT USER_ID FROM USERS ORDER BY USER_ID ASC) WHERE USER_ID = 100002034141760
```

It takes forever (I didn't wait to see the result).

In Big Query:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER() row, USER_ID 
FROM (SELECT USER_ID from USERS.USER_ID ORDER BY USER_ID ASC)
WHERE USER_ID = 1063650153
```

It takes forever (I didn't wait to see the result).

2) Which `USER_ID` is in a particular row (once the table is ordered by `USER_ID`)

For this, I've tried in MySQL:

```
SELECT USER_ID FROM USERS ORDER BY USER_ID ASC LIMIT 150000000000, 1
```

It takes 5 minutes in giving a result. Why? Isn't it supposed to be fast if it has an index?

In Big Query, I didn't find the way because `LIMIT init, num_rows`, doesn't even exist.

I could order the table in a new one, and add a column called `RANK` that orders the `USER_ID`, with an INDEX on it. But it will be a mess if I want to add or remove a row.

Any ideas on how to solve these two queries?

Thanks,
Natalia

Comment: Even though it will be a problem initially, my suggession would be to add another column as rank and update the value once ...

Answer (score 0):

For (1), try this:

```
SELECT count(user_id)
FROM USERS
WHERE USER_ID <= 100001366260516;
```

You can check the `explain`, but it should just be doing a scan of the index.

For (2).  Your question:  "Why? Isn't it supposed to be fast if it has an index?".  Yes, it will use the index.  Then it has to count up to row 150,000,000,000 using an index scan.  Hmmm, that is being the end of the table (if it is not a typo).  In any case, an index scan is quite different from doing an index lookup, which is fast.  And, it will take time.  And more time if the index does not fit into memory.

The proper syntax for `row_number()`, by the way, would be:

```
SELECT row, USER_ID 
FROM (SELECT USER_ID, row_number() over (order by user_id) as row
      from USERS.USER_ID )
WHERE USER_ID = 1063650153;
```

I don't know if it will be that much faster, but at least you are not explicitly ordering the rows first.

If these are the types of queries you need to do, then think about a way to include the ordering information as a column in the table.